# Get a notification from SendGrid when an email is open

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

SendGrid can track when the emails are opened:

[image]

How to get a notification (via email) **when emails are opened**, for which the recipient is different to `myself@gmail.com`? (I don't want to receive a notification when *I open* my own emails sent to myself as BCC).

Do I need to use the SendgridAPI? How? Can I ask Sendgrid to send a notification? (To my server, who will send the notification? To something else?)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to go in *Dashboard > Settings > Mail settings > Event notification*.

[image]

Then here is a possible `eventlistener.php`:

```
<?php

$postdata = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

foreach ($postdata as $event) 
{
    if (($event->event === 'open') && ($event->email !== 'myself@gmail.com'))
    {
        mail('myself@gmail.com', 'Mail to ' . $event->email . ' opened', 'Opened.', "From: myself@gmail.com");
    }
}

?>
```